# Android Notifications: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo

Tags: android, kotlin, android-notifications

I decide to create a class called **LocalNotifications** responsible for handling all notifications from my app separately.

So that all Activities would call this specific class when they want to work with notifications.

**LocalNotifications.kt**

```
import android.app.Application
import android.app.NotificationChannel
import android.app.NotificationManager
import android.content.Context
import android.os.Build
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi
import com.example.notificacoesvls.R

class LocalNotifications: Application() {

    companion object{
        const val CHANNEL_ID = "vls_01"
        const val NOTIFICATION_ID = 1
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    fun createNotificationChannel(){
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
            val channelName = R.string.channel_name
            val channelDescription = R.string.channel_description
            val channelImportance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH

            val channel = NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, channelName.toString(), channelImportance).apply {
                description = channelDescription.toString()
            }

            val notificationManager: NotificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
        }
    }

}
```

As you can see, I had to import an inheritance from the `Application()` class in order to access the `Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE`, otherwise Android would throw an error.

The problem happens when I try to call the `createNotificationChannel()` method through **MainActivity.kt**:

```
private lateinit var notifications: LocalNotifications
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        //Notifications:
        notifications = LocalNotifications()
        notifications.createNotificationChannel()
}
```

The real problem occurs when this command below is executed:

```
val notificationManager: NotificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
```

With the following error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
> ComponentInfo{com.example.notificacoesvls/com.example.notificacoesvls.ui.MainActivity}:
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
> 'java.lang.Object
> android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null
> object reference

How can I solve this error? It is possible to create a separated file for Notifications?

Comment: You cannot create a `LocalNotifications` instance. Most likely, `LocalNotifications` should not extend `Application`, but instead have its function take a `Context` as a parameter. If you are very very certain that you should be extending `Application`, please [read the documentation for `Application`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application?hl=en).

Comment: Hi @CommonsWare, thanks for your answers. In this case, whenever I want to work with Notifications, am I required to create all the logic within Activities? And at most within a WorkManager class? That is, does this mean that it is impossible to create a separate class to handle and generate notifications?

Comment: "whenever I want to work with Notifications, am I required to create all the logic within Activities?" -- no. "does this mean that it is impossible to create a separate class to handle and generate notifications?" -- also no. However, you took a specific approach that is not going to work well, and then implemented in a way that is not going to work at all. Rather than having `LocalNotiications` extend `Application`, have `fun createNotificationChannel(context: Context)`, and use the passed-in `Context` for creating your `NotificationManager`.